# Is there a bot or other method to guide potential question-askers to the most appropriate SE site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, scope

I see that each SE site suggests related questions on that specific site, but I sometimes have questions and am not sure about which SE site is the most appropriate scope for them. Is there a bot or something that can analyze my question and give me the best guess SE site (maybe with confidence values or something of the sort)?

Comment: This question seems belongs to [meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Enzokie I agree. I didn't know that site existed before writing the question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no bot for this. Making such a bot would be quite an ambitious project (but also an exciting one!)

What you can do, is post on Meta Stack Exchange using the [site-recommendation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag. Show the important parts of the question you want to ask, and show what research you've already done to find the appropriate site.

Comment: Either that or post on _what you think_ is the most relevant site and your post will be migrated by the community. I agree that bot would be cool though.

Comment: @George Posting and hoping for migration is risky. It can take a long time before something gets migrated. It is an option, but not one I would advise.

Comment: I agree it is risky as it's more likely that it'll get closed/downvoted but the sense I got from this question was that it was about a question with may have overlapping subjects which would be on topic on both sites so it _shouldn't_ be that bad. That being said, your answer is without a doubt the safer way to go about it.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to look at [the list of sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) and drill down pretty quickly to a couple of possibilities, just based on the broad topics/names. This site even allows you filter by category, so you can quickly narrow down the number of sites you have to consider.

Once you have that, you need to read the Help Center for those candidate sites to see exactly what is on topic there, since different sites have different rules (and some of them may be non-obvious, like [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)).

A bot could conceivably be built to help with the first part, I guess, but that's really the easy part. (Easy part for a human, that is; still hard for a bot.)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, it should be noted that **topicality is not mutually exclusive**.  In other words, there are questions which are on-topic at multiple sites.  When this happens, you get to choose which site to ask.

For example, you can ask questions about the [*Mass Effect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_Effect) franchise's storyline on both [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com) and [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com).  For this case, I would recommend Arqade for questions more oriented towards player choices and gameplay ("How do I make [character] like me more?"), and Sci-fi & Fantasy for questions more oriented towards world building and storytelling ("Why is [character] so hostile towards [protagonist]?").  These areas are not totally equivalent; if you want to ask a pure gameplay question ("How do I beat the boss battle at the end of [level]?"), that's only going to work on Arqade.  But there is a lot of overlap, and we trust that questioners will choose a site wisely.

Of course, you may get a different style of answer, depending on which site you choose.  The best way to learn which questions are appropriate for which sites is to *join more sites*, and participate in them regularly.  You can also learn a lot by just reading Hot Network Questions, but bear in mind that these are sometimes unrepresentative of the site as a whole.